# Few questions on generator expressions and speed efficient alternatives

Tags: python, functional-programming, generator, bytecode-manipulation, lambda

Consider the following code, integral to my questions below:

```
import functools

N = 3

class Struct:
    """Create an instance with argument=value slots.
    This is for making a lightweight object whose class doesn't matter."""
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

    def __repr__(self):

        args = ['%s=%s' % (k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in vars(self).items()]
        return '\nStruct(%s)' % ', '.join(args)

def doit( move ):

    ( rowIn, colIn ) = move
    something = rowIn  + ( 10 * colIn ) # An involved computation here in real life

    return Struct( coord = ( rowIn, colIn ), something = something )

legalStates = [ ( row, col ) for row in xrange( N ) for col in xrange( N ) ] # A more complicated function that generates the list in real life. Call it 'complicatedFunction'

genExpFn = lambda : ( ( s.something, m, s ) for ( m, s ) in ( ( move, doit( move ) ) for move in legalStates ) )  #Q1

successorsSortedGenFn = lambda : ( p for p in sorted( genExpFn(), reverse = True ) )

def bFunc( s, a ):

    #print "a * s ->", a * s
    return a * s # An involved computation here in real life

def aFunc( ( v, m, s ) ): #Q2

    assert( s.something == v )
    return bFunc( s.something, 10 )

print "min( successorsSortedGen ) -> " + str( min( successorsSortedGenFn(), key=functools.partial( aFunc )) ) #Q3
print
print "max( successorsSortedGen ) -> " + str( max( successorsSortedGenFn(), key=functools.partial( aFunc )) ) #Q4
```

My questions are based on the statements marked as "#Q":

**Q1** : It's apparent that the generator is completely instantiated ( all elements are executed ), as we call `sorted()` on it ( which generates all the elements and creates a temporary unsorted list which it sorts and returns as a new list? ).

Is there a space efficient way, that minimizes the creation of temporaries *and* yeilds a sorted list?

I tried to, but could not write a list comprehension that could sort in place using `list.sort()`

This was the kind of expression I was thinking about:

```
successorsSorted = [ ( s.something, m, s ) for ( m, s ) in ( ( move, doit( move ) ) for move in legalStates ) ].sort( reverse = True )
```

**Q2** : Notice that 'aFunc' is just a wrapper around 'bFunc' because I was not able to write an equivalent representation in the `functools.partial( aFunc )` call.

What is the expression 'aFunc' in `functools.partial( aFunc )` that I am looking for *that will allow me to call 'bFunc' directly*?

---

**EDIT** : The answer to Q2 is `lambda ( v, m, s ): bFunc(s.something, 10)`

Thus, the statements become:

```
print "min( successorsSortedGen ) -> " + str( min( successorsSortedGenFn(), key=functools.partial( lambda ( v, m, s ): bFunc(s.something, 10)) ) )
print
print "max( successorsSortedGen ) -> " + str( max( successorsSortedGenFn(), key=functools.partial( lambda ( v, m, s ): bFunc(s.something, 10)) ) )
```

I know it kinda seems lame I did not think about this earlier, but oh well ( thanks to aaronasterling for the gentle prodding ).

---

**Q3, Q4** : Note that the elements passed to min() and max() are already sorted.

Is it possible for me to make this hint to min() and max() so that it does not instantiate the whole list as a temporary and then iterate through the whole list to locate the min or max element?

If not, is there a module or custom function in existence that does not instantiate the whole list, but, given that the list passed to it is sorted, returns the min or max element *while inspecting the least number of elements*?

Comment: @PoorLuzer: A very liberal use of list comprehension can sometimes leave the program unreadable.

Comment: I don't think it's the list comprehensions here. I think it's the spaces around all the brackets. It's __Hideous__.

Comment: @aaronasterling : Is it really that painful? I like to put redundant spaces in my code ( between lines and around parens ) - kind of helps me read better - really :-(

Comment: @PoorLuzer. Don't take it personally. We all have our own tastes. The spaces between the lines aren't so bad but I can barely read the code with that many spaces around the brackets. For just a function call (where I normally see that style), its not so bad but when seriously nested, it's (to me at least) a major distraction.

Comment: @aaronasterling : None taken. I have read the Python style list and it's against what I have done, but it seems too compressed. Hmm.. maybe it will help to conform. Do you have a style different from the "official one" that is "more readable"?

Comment: Follow PEP 8 and learn to live with the bits you disagree with. If nothing else, it'll keep the noise down in the comments to your questions.

Comment: If you want to get the min and max of a sorted sequence, take the first element and last element in that sequence. `first = next(iter(container))` and `for item in container: last = item` are just examples of what you could possible write, and they were with generators/iterators. If you have an actual list or tuple, you can write `first, last = container[0], container[-1]` instead. `FastTable` may be of use to you, but I ended up going with `heapq` to solve the problem I had been facing. After analyzing my problem in more detail and altering my approach, `heapq` was a perfect answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. `[x for x in somelist].sort()` creates a list and calls the `sort` method. This returns `None` The assignment assigns `None` to `successorSorted`. If you want to do this, you'll have to implement it yourself and it will probably be way slower than the builtin sort creating the temporary list.

Q2. You could take apart the code object and rearrange the argument list so that `a` is the first argument and then rewrite all the bytecode to account for the new positions of the locals. (Yes this can actually be done). You could then use `functools.partial` on that. Or you could use a wrapper like you're doing now or in a few other ways. I'm +1 on the wrapper. (though let me know if you want a bytecode hack, I think they're fun and the cool thing about providing them as answers on Stack Overflow is that I get to write them but don't have to use them ;)

Q3, Q4. Not really. To get the tenth element of an iterator, you need to go through all of the earlier ones. If you know that you want the first element, you can just do

```
smallest = next(sorted_iterator)
```

and for the last

```
for item in iterable: pass
largest = item
```

The first will eat the first element of the iterator and the last will eat your whole iterator. Bye Bye iterator.

Comment: Does this mean that, for this use case, I would be better off using list comprehensions instead?

Comment: @PoorLuzer, you would have to profile it. I recall `sort` being slightly faster when passed a list comprehension but I don't know for sure. Whatever you pass in to sorted will be copied though.

Comment: @aaronasterling : I like how you asked me to profile! That way you cannot go wrong :-D I am interested in *seeing* the bytecode hack, just because it can be done; won't probably use it though. Can't a clever lambda expression or a getattr() get it done?

Comment: @PoorLuzer. sure. If you want a lambda, `wrapped = lambda s: bfunc(s, 10)`. I'll do the bytecode thing but probably not tonight.

Comment: @aaronasterling : I am not complaining, will like seeing it though.

Comment: @aaronasterling : I must have been sleepy last night, but after lunch, when I read this again, I realized that the suggested lambda above would not work : key=functools.partial( wrapped = lambda s: bfunc(s, 10) )). This is because the argument to 'wrapped' is a tripleton ( ( v, m, s ) ), while the lambda expects a singleton! Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @PoorLuzer, `lambda v, m, s: bfuncs((v, m, s), 10)`. It's pretty much the same as your function but with a lambda instead.

Comment: @aaronasterling : You meant `key=functools.partial( lambda v, m, s: bfuncs(s.something, 10))?`. Will profile it. Would we be getting the bytecode hack? :-D

Comment: @ PoorLuzer. The lambda is in liu of using `partial`

Comment: @aaronasterling : Yes I realized that. However, would not using partial be still useful since it works on a generator?

Comment: @aaronasterling : Marking yours as the answer. Excellent work! I would have liked to see the bytecode hack though. Any possibility?